# 1-D transformation to make data points linearly separable

Tags: linear-transformations, machine-learning

We are given a 1 dimensional dataset. The points between $2k$ and $2k+1$ are labeled by X. The points between $2k+1$ and $2k+2$ are labeled by O. You can see their representation in the following image : [image: 1-D dataset representation]

What I am trying to do is to find a 1 dimensional transformation to make these data points linearly separable.

---

My idea was to use a function that would be a identity function for the points between 2k and 2k+1, and return the inverse for the points between $2k+1$ and $2k+2$. But that only works in the case of positive values. I am a bit lost since I am not even sure these points can become linearly separable. Does such a tranformation exist ? Or is there any way to prove that such a transformation doesn't exist?

Thank you

Comment: Please define what you mean exactly by "linearly separable" and by "1 dimensional transformation".

Comment: By 1 dimensional I mean that the output of the function is of dimension 1. What I mean by "linearly separable" is a tranformation that would group all the O points together, and all the X points together. Such that it would be possible to draw a line with all the O points on one side of the line and all the X points on the other side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, applying the function $\sin(\pi x)$ will result in the red Xs being positive and the green Os being negative.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works just fine.